# Open microsoft excel sheet instead of Saving to computer

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can anybody help me with how to open an excel sheet in vb.net without saving it ?
I want to export the data of DataGridView to excel for editing and then get it back to DataGridView and in this case I dont want to save this excel sheet to computer but simply open it for editing and then close after data has been imported back to DataGridView.

Edit- below is the dode

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enter code hereButton2.Click

    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next

    Dim xlpath As String = Path.GetTempPath()

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(xlpath & "checkfile.xlsx")

    Process.Start(xlpath & "checkfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Why don't you save it to a temporary file for editing?

Comment: you mean saving it to a temporary folder and then deleting it ?
im actually trying to save the excel file to memory stream, open it and then close it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file in [`Path.GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx) folder and open it with [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In order to reload data in your `DataGridView` you can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Hi Tezzo, thanks for your reply but can you please give me an example for this ?
im new at this. I have attached my code with the question.

Comment: Give a look at this example (set .Filter with your file name and on Changed event send data to DataGridView): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2